# Count numbers in given low-high range using Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, range

I'm trying to count how many numbers in the input list are in the given low-high range.

Here's what I have so far:

```
countRange :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> Int
countRange  _ _ [] = 0
countRange low high (x:xs)  | (low < x) && (high > x) = 1 + (countRange low high xs)
                            | otherwise = countRange low high xs
```

Some examples:

- `countRange 5 8 []` ==> `0`
- `countRange 1 3 [1,2,3,4,5]` ==> `3`

Comment: Shouldn't the bounds be inclusive here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is more of a semantical discussion. Your code works fine if we assume that the ranges are *exclusive*. But your example suggest that the bounds are *inclusive*, so we can rewrite this to:

```
countRange :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> Int
countRange  _ _ [] = 0
countRange low high (x:xs)  | low <= x && high >= x = 1 + countRange low high xs
                            | otherwise = countRange low high xs
```

But I think you make it too hard here. You can count the number of elements in a list with `length`, and we can filter the elements with `filter`, so we can write it in a compact way with:

```
countRange :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> Int
countRange low hig = length . filter f
    where f x = x >= low && x <= hig
```

Note that we can generalize the function signature without any additional effort:

```
countRange :: Ord a => a -> a -> [a] -> Int
countRange low hig = length . filter f
    where f x = x >= low && x <= hig
```